# An equivalence relation on Dedekind cuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

The definition of a cut $(A,B)$ is:

$$
  \mathbb{Q} = A \cup B \\
  A \ne \emptyset ,B \ne \emptyset  \\
  \forall a \in A,\forall b \in B,a < b \\ $$

Define a relation on the set of all cuts of $\mathbb{Q}$ by

$(A,B) \sim ({A_1},{B_1})$

if and only if

$\operatorname{card} (A\Delta {A_1}) \leqslant 1$

I want to prove this is an equivalence relation. Reflexivity and symmetry is obvious. But transitivity confuses me. Concretely I have to prove

If $(A,B) \sim ({A_1},{B_1})$ and $(A_1,B_1) \sim ({A_2},{B_2})$, then $(A,B) \sim ({A_2},{B_2})$.

Thank Andrés Caicedo! It has been cracked already.

(1) If $(A,B) \sim ({A_1},{B_1})$, then $A \subset {A_1}$ or $A_1 \subset A$.

(2) Suppose $(A,B) \sim ({A_1},{B_1})$ and wlog $A \subset {A_1}$. If $A$ has a maximum, then $A_1 = A$ must hold. If $A$ has not a maximum and $A_1 \ne A$, then $A_1$ has only one more point than $A$ and $A_1$ has a maximum.

(3) To conclude, if $(A,B) \sim ({A_1},{B_1})$, then $A$ and $A_1$ can be derived from a same set without a maximum (geometrically "half of rationals") and differ at most one point which is supposed to become the maximum.

(4) In the above view, it is obvious that transitivity holds. So it is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Suppose that $(A,B)\sim(A_1,B_1)$ but $A\ne A_1$. What can you deduce? If you are not sure what to say, try to find examples of this situation.

Comment: Guess my last erased comment was too much of a spoiler... sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks. The critical case is that $A_1$ has one more point than $A$ and $A_2$ has one more point than $A_1$. Then I can deduce a contradicion by the fact that there are infinitely many rational numbers between any two distinct rational numbers.

Comment: When using Dedekind cuts to define the Dedekind completion of $Q$ (or of any linear order), it may be more convenient to restrict our attention to those cuts $(A,B)$ for which neither $\max A$ nor $\min B$ exist.